# PHP: Undefined Offset at 0, but it's there (I think)

Tags: php, undefined, offset

So I've got a 2-D array, of phrases and individual words, called `$frags`, that `var_dump's like so:

```
array(4) { 
[0]=> array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "the" [1]=> string(4) "term" [2]=> string(4) "'AI'" [3]=> string(5) "still" [4]=> string(7) "manages" } 
[1]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(2) "to" [1]=> string(5) "creep" } 
[2]=> array(3) { 
    [0]=> string(4) "into" [1]=> string(2) "my" [2]=> string(6) "speech" } 
[3]=> array(2) { 
    [0]=> string(2) "or" [1]=> string(8) "writing." } 
}
```

When I `var_dump($frags[0])` it gives me:

```
array(5) { 
    [0]=> string(3) "the" [1]=> string(4) "term" [2]=> string(4) "'AI'" [3]=> string(5) "still" [4]=> string(7) "manages" }
```

But when I try to print `$frags[0][0]` it gives me:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\jpsmythe\parser.php on line 57
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\wamp\www\jpsmythe\parser.php on line 57
>
> string(3) "the"

which does not make sense. I feel like I've tried everything, including treating the 0 like a string, but it's still not seeing it. Help?

The relevant code:

```
private function clause($frags) {
   // set the parser through the control hub
    $controller = Controller::getInstance();
    $parser = $controller->parser;
    $parser->init();

   // take the $frags array from elsewhere in the program
   // this $frags is actually punctuation-separated fragments of a sentence, not the  same as the $frags array with which I'm having problems now   
    $i = 0;
    $clauses = array();
   //run through the punctuated $frags array
    while ($i < count($frags)) {
        $pos = array();
        $num = 0;
        $p = 0;
// separated each punc'ed fragment into smaller fragments separated by stopwords        
        while ($p < count($frags[$i])) {
            if (array_key_exists($frags[$i][$p], $parser->stopwords)) {
                $pos[] = $p;
                $clauses[$num] = array();
                $num ++;
            }
            $p ++;
        }
        $pos[] = count($frags[$i]);

        $num = 0;
        $j = 0;
        if (count($pos) > 0) {
            while ($j < count($pos)) {
                $stop = FALSE;
                $k = $pos[$j]-1;
                while ($k >= 0 && !$stop) {
                    if (array_key_exists($frags[$i][$k], $parser->stopwords))
                        $stop = TRUE;
                    $clauses[$num][] = $frags[$i][$k];
                    $k --;
                }
                
                $clauses[$num] = array_reverse($clauses[$num]);
                $num ++;
                $j ++;
            }

           //send the array of stopped fragments to the parser
            $parser->parse($clauses);
            //$controller->setResponse($clauses);
        }
        $i ++;
    }
}

function parse($frags) {
    $i = 0;
    
    // more code here, commented out for the time being
    // below, send response to control hub for output
    $controller = Controller::getInstance();
    $controller->setResponse($frags[$i][0]);
}
```

Comment: Indeed, that doesn't make sense. Please paste the dump again using `var_dump()` and stackoverflow's code formatting and please paste the actual code and the actual error message. Must be a typo or something.

Comment: Version is 5.3.0. I'll post the most relevant part of the code; this is a very small part of a much larger program.

Comment: Can you tell us which line is line 57?

Comment: `$controller->setResponse($frags[$i][0]);`

Comment: I can see now that it is supplying the correct answer, though what I can't see now is why it might be, a) going through these motions thrice, and b) only finding the correct answer on the third try. There are no other calls to the response function elsewhere in the program right now.

Comment: If you can, step through the code with a debugger, keeping a watch on `$frags`

Comment: It seems there's nothing wrong with your array, because it still prints the correct answer. So maybe there's another place. Can you tell us which line is line 57?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an

`if (isset($frags[$i][0])) {`

to the top of the parser function seems to have fixed it. Which is fair enough, but I'm still not entirely sure I get it.

Comment: Put an `else { echo "Hey! It seems that {$frags[$i]} has no [0] offset (in \$frags[$i])\n" }` and test where does it fail ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me...

```
$frags = array(array ('the', 'term', '\'AI\'', 'still', 'manages'), array ('to', 'creep'), array ('into', 'my', 'speech'), array ('or', 'writing.'));

print_r($frags);
```

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => the [1]
>   => term [2] => 'AI' [3] => still [4] => manages ) [1] => Array ( [0] => to [1] => creep ) [2] => Array ( [0] =>
>   into [1] => my [2] => speech ) [3] =>
>   Array ( [0] => or [1] => writing. ) )

```
print "<br>";
print_r($frags[0]);
```

> Array ( [0] => the [1] => term [2] =>
>   'AI' [3] => still [4] => manages )

```
print "<br>";
print $frags[0][0];
```

> the

Answer (score 0):

The value `$frags` is declared outside of the code you've pasted (in the calling scope of the call to ::clause(), probably). This happens quite often in a variable name conflict. Consider this:

```
<?php
$frags = array('apple','orange');
// other stuff
while ($frags = $query->next()) {
  //...
}
// the last value returned from $query->next() was false in this example
// .. more stuff

$this->clause($frags); // actually passes false, not the apple,orange array
```

This happens to the best of us (-:

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `$parser->stopwords` is it's hard to run your sample to see where it's failing. But my first observation is that you aren't passing $frags into parse(), you're passing $clauses. And it's possible that you get through the loops that convert $frags to $clauses without ever assigning anything into $clauses[0].

I would suggest you vardump or print_r $clauses just before the call to parse.

Also, I question which [0] is failing? the first or the second? Easy way to tell... do this in parse:

```
function parse($frags) {
    $i = 0;

    // more code here, commented out for the time being
    // below, send response to control hub for output
    $controller = Controller::getInstance();

    if (!isset($frags[$i])) echo "failure at ".__LINE__." [$i]\n";
    if (!isset($frags[$i][0])) echo "failure at ".__LINE__." [$i][0]\n";

    $controller->setResponse($frags[$i][0]);
}
```

That should be informative as to which index is causing php to puke.

Answer (score 0):

```
$grabs = array(0=> array(0=>"the",1=>"term",2=>"AI",3=> "still",4=> "manages"),
                1=> array(0=>"to",1=>"creep"),
                2=> array(0=>"into", 1=>"my" ,2=>"speech"),
                3=> array(0=> "or",1=>"writing")
                );
 echo $grabs[0][0];
```